# Using Selenium Cross-Platofrm, How Do I Test on Mac, Mobile and PC Versions of Browsers

Tags: selenium

I am a completely beginner with Selenium so bear with me :)

I'm hoping to test a web application on both the Mac and PC version of the common browsers (chrome, FF, IE, Safari) and also to test on the iphone and android browsers.

To do this, do I need to have selenium set up on both a mac and on a pc?  How exactly do I set up a test suite that I can execute from a linux server that will execute tests on browsers from different platforms.

Is there any way to run the tests directly on the server or will it need to connect to a PC and a Mac that are both properly configured to run the needed tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Selenium Grid and then Run nodes on each of the platforms with browser applicable for that machine.

For Hub: (Run this where you test framework is setup)

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar -role hub
```

For a firefox based node: Ex: Say Windows machine with firefox

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar -role webdriver -hub `http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5556 -browser browserName=firefox`
```

For google-chrome based node: Ex: Say Linux machine with firefox

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser browserName=chrome
```